# the_excerpt() in Wordpress is too slow

Tags: wordpress

I have many posts in my Wordpress blog.

These posts are very long and have not `<!--more-->`.

So I have to use the_excerpt() function to create excerpt of post automatically.

But the time cost is too long.

I render top ten posts using about 8 seconds.

I try to print the the_excerpt() execution time like below.

```
<div class="description">
    <?php timer_start(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php echo timer_stop(); ?>
</div>
```

The time is between 0.8s~2s.

It is so strange...

So how can I improve the speed of page rendering?

Thank you all!

Comment: 8 seconds seems way too long for just the_excerpt(). How long (measured in words) are your posts? Are you sure there isn´t something different blocking or slowing your site?

Comment: It cannot be `the_excerpt()`. If it is this, then your posts has to be huge, and I mean huge like hundreds of megabytes. Download and install Query Monitor and check which piece of code is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for you advice! I use the Query Monitor.

Comment: Page generation time: 8.3757  1.4% of 600s limit;  Peak memory usage: 37,307 kB 14.2% of 262,144 kB limit; Database query time: 0.0234

Comment: I still do not find the reason why cost 8 seconds... The database query only cost 0.02s...

Comment: I am having the same issue. Just dont understand why the_exerpt() function is taking so long.